# SQL Server Express 2008 R2 Installation error at Windows 7

Tags: installation, sql-server-express, sql-server-2008-express, sql-server-2008-r2

I created an install script that will install SQL Server 2008 R2 on Windows XP SP3, Windows Vista and Windows 7.

One of the commands that I used in the installation is for the silent installation of SQL Server 2008 R2. 
When I install it on windows XP everything works just fine, but when I try to install it on Windows 7 I get an error.

What am I doing wrong?

Here is the command line that I use:

```
Setup.exe /ConfigurationFile=Mysetup.ini
```

Mysetup.ini file:

```
-------------------------------------Start of ini file ---------------------------------

;SQL SERVER 2008 R2 Configuration File

;Version 1.0, 5 May 2010

;

[SQLSERVER2008]

; Specify the Instance ID for the SQL Server features you have specified. SQL Server directory structure, registry structure, and service names will reflect the instance ID of the SQL Server instance.

INSTANCEID="MSSQLSERVER"

; Specifies a Setup work flow, like INSTALL, UNINSTALL, or UPGRADE. This is a required parameter.

ACTION="Install"

; Specifies features to install, uninstall, or upgrade. The list of top-level features include SQL, AS, RS, IS, and Tools. The SQL feature will install the database engine, replication, and full-text. The Tools feature will install Management Tools, Books online, Business Intelligence Development Studio, and other shared components.

FEATURES=SQLENGINE

; Displays the command line parameters usage

HELP="False"

; Specifies that the detailed Setup log should be piped to the console.

INDICATEPROGRESS="False"

; Setup will not display any user interface.

QUIET="False"

; Setup will display progress only without any user interaction.

QUIETSIMPLE="True"

; Specifies that Setup should install into WOW64. This command line argument is not supported on an IA64 or a 32-bit system.

;X86="False"

; Specifies the path to the installation media folder where setup.exe is located.

;MEDIASOURCE="z:\"

; Detailed help for command line argument ENU has not been defined yet.

ENU="True"

; Parameter that controls the user interface behavior. Valid values are Normal for the full UI, and AutoAdvance for a simplied UI.

; UIMODE="Normal"

; Specify if errors can be reported to Microsoft to improve future SQL Server releases. Specify 1 or True to enable and 0 or False to disable this feature.

ERRORREPORTING="False"

; Specify the root installation directory for native shared components.

;INSTALLSHAREDDIR="D:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server"

; Specify the root installation directory for the WOW64 shared components.

;INSTALLSHAREDWOWDIR="D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server"

; Specify the installation directory.

;INSTANCEDIR="D:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server"

; Specify that SQL Server feature usage data can be collected and sent to Microsoft. Specify 1 or True to enable and 0 or False to disable this feature.

SQMREPORTING="False"

; Specify a default or named instance. MSSQLSERVER is the default instance for non-Express editions and SQLExpress for Express editions. This parameter is required when installing the SQL Server Database Engine (SQL), Analysis Services (AS), or Reporting Services (RS).

INSTANCENAME="SQLEXPRESS"

SECURITYMODE=SQL

SAPWD=SystemAdmin

; Agent account name

AGTSVCACCOUNT="NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE"

; Auto-start service after installation.

AGTSVCSTARTUPTYPE="Manual"

; Startup type for Integration Services.

;ISSVCSTARTUPTYPE="Automatic"

; Account for Integration Services: Domain\User or system account.

;ISSVCACCOUNT="NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService"

; Controls the service startup type setting after the service has been created.

;ASSVCSTARTUPTYPE="Automatic"

; The collation to be used by Analysis Services.

;ASCOLLATION="Latin1_General_CI_AS"

; The location for the Analysis Services data files.

;ASDATADIR="Data"

; The location for the Analysis Services log files.

;ASLOGDIR="Log"

; The location for the Analysis Services backup files.

;ASBACKUPDIR="Backup"

; The location for the Analysis Services temporary files.

;ASTEMPDIR="Temp"

; The location for the Analysis Services configuration files.

;ASCONFIGDIR="Config"

; Specifies whether or not the MSOLAP provider is allowed to run in process.

;ASPROVIDERMSOLAP="1"

; A port number used to connect to the SharePoint Central Administration web application.

;FARMADMINPORT="0"

; Startup type for the SQL Server service.

SQLSVCSTARTUPTYPE="Automatic"

; Level to enable FILESTREAM feature at (0, 1, 2 or 3).

FILESTREAMLEVEL="0"

; Set to "1" to enable RANU for SQL Server Express.

ENABLERANU="1"

; Specifies a Windows collation or an SQL collation to use for the Database Engine.

SQLCOLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"

; Account for SQL Server service: Domain\User or system account.

SQLSVCACCOUNT="NT Authority\System"

; Default directory for the Database Engine user databases.

;SQLUSERDBDIR="K:\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL\Data"

; Default directory for the Database Engine user database logs.

;SQLUSERDBLOGDIR="L:\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL\Data\Logs"

; Directory for Database Engine TempDB files.

;SQLTEMPDBDIR="T:\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL\Data"

; Directory for the Database Engine TempDB log files.

;SQLTEMPDBLOGDIR="T:\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL\Data\Logs"

; Provision current user as a Database Engine system administrator for SQL Server 2008 R2 Express.

ADDCURRENTUSERASSQLADMIN="True"

; Specify 0 to disable or 1 to enable the TCP/IP protocol.

TCPENABLED="1"

; Specify 0 to disable or 1 to enable the Named Pipes protocol.

NPENABLED="0"

; Startup type for Browser Service.

BROWSERSVCSTARTUPTYPE="Automatic"

; Specifies how the startup mode of the report server NT service. When

; Manual - Service startup is manual mode (default).

; Automatic - Service startup is automatic mode.

; Disabled - Service is disabled

;RSSVCSTARTUPTYPE="Automatic"

; Specifies which mode report server is installed in.

; Default value: “FilesOnly”

;RSINSTALLMODE="FilesOnlyMode"

; Accept SQL Server 2008 R2 license terms

IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS="TRUE"

;setup.exe /CONFIGURATIONFILE=Mysetup.ini /INDICATEPROGRESS

--------------------------- End of ini file -------------------------------------
```

And I get this error:

```
2010-08-31 18:05:53 Slp: Error result: -2068119551

2010-08-31 18:05:53 Slp: Result facility code: 1211

2010-08-31 18:05:53 Slp: Result error code: 1

2010-08-31 18:05:53 Slp: Sco: Attempting to create base registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, machine 

2010-08-31 18:05:53 Slp: Sco: Attempting to open registry subkey 

2010-08-31 18:05:53 Slp: Sco: Attempting to open registry subkey Software\Microsoft\PCHealth\ErrorReporting\DW\Installed

2010-08-31 18:05:53 Slp: Sco: Attempting to get registry value DW0200

2010-08-31 18:05:53 Slp: Submitted 1 of 1 failures to the Watson data repository
```

What does this mean? What do I need to do to fix the problem?

Here is the Summary file:

```
Overall summary:

  Final result:                  SQL Server installation failed. To continue, investigate the reason for the failure, correct the problem, uninstall SQL Server, and then rerun SQL Server Setup.

  Exit code (Decimal):           -2068119551

  Exit facility code:            1211

  Exit error code:               1

  Exit message:                  SQL Server installation failed. To continue, investigate the reason for the failure, correct the problem, uninstall SQL Server, and then rerun SQL Server Setup.

  Start time:                    2010-08-31 18:03:44

  End time:                      2010-08-31 18:05:51

  Requested action:              Install

  Log with failure:              C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20100831_180236\Detail.txt

  Exception help link:           http%3a%2f%2fgo.microsoft.com%2ffwlink%3fLinkId%3d20476%26ProdName%3dMicrosoft%2bSQL%2bServer%26EvtSrc%3dsetup.rll%26EvtID%3d50000%26ProdVer%3d10.50.1600.1%26EvtType%3d0x6121810A%400xC24842DB



Machine Properties:

  Machine name:                  NVR

  Machine processor count:       2

  OS version:                    Windows 7

  OS service pack:               

  OS region:                     United States

  OS language:                   English (United States)

  OS architecture:               x86

  Process architecture:          32 Bit

  OS clustered:                  No



Product features discovered:

  Product              Instance             Instance ID                    Feature                                  Language             Edition              Version         Clustered 



Package properties:

  Description:                   SQL Server Database Services 2008 R2

  ProductName:                   SQL Server 2008 R2

  Type:                          RTM

  Version:                       10

  SPLevel:                       0

  Installation location:         C:\Disk1\setupsql\x86\setup\

  Installation edition:          EXPRESS



User Input Settings:

  ACTION:                        Install

  ADDCURRENTUSERASSQLADMIN:      True

  AGTSVCACCOUNT:                 NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE

  AGTSVCPASSWORD:                *****

  AGTSVCSTARTUPTYPE:             Disabled

  ASBACKUPDIR:                   Backup

  ASCOLLATION:                   Latin1_General_CI_AS

  ASCONFIGDIR:                   Config

  ASDATADIR:                     Data

  ASDOMAINGROUP:                 <empty>

  ASLOGDIR:                      Log

  ASPROVIDERMSOLAP:              1

  ASSVCACCOUNT:                  <empty>

  ASSVCPASSWORD:                 *****

  ASSVCSTARTUPTYPE:              Automatic

  ASSYSADMINACCOUNTS:            <empty>

  ASTEMPDIR:                     Temp

  BROWSERSVCSTARTUPTYPE:         Automatic

  CONFIGURATIONFILE:             C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20100831_180236\ConfigurationFile.ini

  CUSOURCE:                      

  ENABLERANU:                    True

  ENU:                           True

  ERRORREPORTING:                False

  FARMACCOUNT:                   <empty>

  FARMADMINPORT:                 0

  FARMPASSWORD:                  *****

  FEATURES:                      SQLENGINE

  FILESTREAMLEVEL:               0

  FILESTREAMSHARENAME:           <empty>

  FTSVCACCOUNT:                  <empty>

  FTSVCPASSWORD:                 *****

  HELP:                          False

  IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS:  True

  INDICATEPROGRESS:              False

  INSTALLSHAREDDIR:              C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\

  INSTALLSHAREDWOWDIR:           C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\

  INSTALLSQLDATADIR:             <empty>

  INSTANCEDIR:                   C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\

  INSTANCEID:                    MSSQLSERVER

  INSTANCENAME:                  SQLEXPRESS

  ISSVCACCOUNT:                  NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService

  ISSVCPASSWORD:                 *****

  ISSVCSTARTUPTYPE:              Automatic

  NPENABLED:                     0

  PASSPHRASE:                    *****

  PCUSOURCE:                     

  PID:                           *****

  QUIET:                         False

  QUIETSIMPLE:                   True

  ROLE:                          AllFeatures_WithDefaults

  RSINSTALLMODE:                 FilesOnlyMode

  RSSVCACCOUNT:                  NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE

  RSSVCPASSWORD:                 *****

  RSSVCSTARTUPTYPE:              Automatic

  SAPWD:                         *****

  SECURITYMODE:                  SQL

  SQLBACKUPDIR:                  <empty>

  SQLCOLLATION:                  SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

  SQLSVCACCOUNT:                 NT Authority\System

  SQLSVCPASSWORD:                *****

  SQLSVCSTARTUPTYPE:             Automatic

  SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS:           <empty>

  SQLTEMPDBDIR:                  <empty>

  SQLTEMPDBLOGDIR:               <empty>

  SQLUSERDBDIR:                  <empty>

  SQLUSERDBLOGDIR:               <empty>

  SQMREPORTING:                  False

  TCPENABLED:                    1

  UIMODE:                        AutoAdvance

  X86:                           False

   Configuration file:            C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20100831_180236\ConfigurationFile.ini 

Detailed results:

  Feature:                       Database Engine Services

  Status:                        Failed: see logs for details

  MSI status:                    Passed

  Configuration status:          Failed: see details below

  Configuration error code:      0x0A2FBD17@1211@1

  Configuration error description: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.  

  Configuration log:             C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20100831_180236\Detail.txt 

Rules with failures: 

Global rules: 

Scenario specific rules:

Rules report file:               C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20100831_180236\SystemConfigurationCheck_Report.htm
```

Comment: I assume you are running the install on windows 7 as an administrator?

Comment: I am also experiencing the same issue even after following a tutorial carefully. Even though this question has been asked several years ago, please let me know if you have solved this.